# Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject - why are my files always locked (by me!) when I try to open them?

Tags: .net, ms-project

I'm trying to use Interop to manipulate MS Project 2003 (MPP) files.

My problem is that MS Project reports that the files is already opened by another user (me!) and that I can open it only as read-only.

Obviously, I've tried to restart studio, then windows (xp) but with no effect.
The file attribute for Readonly is cleared on the file.

Any suggestions for what I might try?!

Thanks,

Anders

Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject
...
        Dim app As ApplicationClass = New ApplicationClass()
        app.Visible = False
        Dim success As Boolean = app.FileOpen(fullPath, False)

Comment: I found the problem to be my own application under development; I was using Aspose.Tasks and just let the Aspose variable run out of scope. The solution was to set the reference Nothing, call GC and still try repeatedly to open the file until the opening succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tow things came to my mind, first see if in your code your opening the file elsewhere.
second see if there is a process in the background using the file.